# How to include an external jar in a GWT module?

Tags: gwt

I would like to use the `org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator` class in a view class of my GWT web app. I have read that I have to implicitely tell that I intend to use this external library. I thought adding the next line into my `App.gwt.xml` would work.

`<inherits name='org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator'/>`

I get the next error:

```
    Loading inherited module 'org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator'
       [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/apache/commons/validator/GenericValidator.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
    [ERROR] Line 13: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
    com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:239)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:270)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2747)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:327)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
[ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:56)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:270)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2747)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:327)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
[ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:351)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
```

I have `commons.validator-1.3.1.jar` in `war/WEB-INF/lib`

I am using eclipse with Google Plugin.

Anyone knows how it works?

Answer (score 8):

The syntax `<inherits name='package.SomeModule'/>` is only for special GWT modules, built to be used with GWT, not generics Java libraries ([docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideInheritingModules)). A quick test to see if a jar/library is built to be used with GWT is to see if it includes a module file. If you look at the error you posted the top line reads:

```
Loading inherited module 'org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator'
       [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/apache/commons/validator/GenericValidator.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

You can see that `commons.validator` is missing the required module file. You can still use this library on the server side (no restrictions there). For client side, chances are GWT doesn't emulate the required parts of Java - for more information [see the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html).

Comment: I wish there was a work-around for this. If I /know/ a certain class could be compiled into JavaScript by GWT I still can't include it if it's not in a GWT module.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can add the GWT module XML file to your project.  I've had to do this in the past.

This is not "ideal", but it saves you from having to repackage the jars.

In this case, you could create a file named "Commons.gwt.xml" and put it in a `/org/apache/commons` directory in your local source path.  The file would contain:

```xml
<module>
    <source path="validator"/>
</module>
```

Then, you would just need to add the line `<inherits name="org.apache.commons.Common">` to your application.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do if this was your library would be to add in a XXX.gwt.xml file for each package that you want GWT to be able to compile to.  This is how you would add in a shared jar for instance into a GWT frontend of a multi-tiered (and multi-server) app.  You can take any of the GWT libraries and unzip their jars to see what I mean, there will be a file called XXX.gwt.xml one level above all packages that GWT needs to be able to use to compile.

In the past I have taken and re-packaged some of these open source libraries, which you could do here. This is problematic since then you really need to source control your version of the library, and would have to manually merge any new changes (or just redo the XXX.gwt.xml file entries and repackage).

So this is not the best case scenario (but sometimes you're looking for miss right now and not miss right), is there no way around this just using core GWT and Java?  I know the pre-fab libraries are great, but is the dependency with the extra work worth the time savings in you particular case?

I hope that helps.